# Can we use coordinator pattern in swift package manager?

Tags: swift, swift5

I am trying to use coordinator pattern in my swift package manager. but not able to display view when first view controller. i am using storyboard. can anyone help me on this?

```
public func loadScreen() -> ViewController? {
        let vc = ViewController ()
        let navi = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        fisrtCoordinator = FirstCoordinator(navigationController: navi)
        fisrtCoordinator?.start()
        return vc
    }
```

Comment: You can use coordinator pattern regardless from your SPM, i couldn`t get the question

Comment: @zeytin When i am trying to call the ViewController directly from SPM then its working fine, but when i am trying through coordinator then its showing black screen